# stuck on error related to android studio. it is showing error on below lines of code

Tags: android

```
1> if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
   // I am getting red text on action_settings
2> getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homepage, menu);
   // here i am getting red text on homepage
```

**I had reused the following code but getting red text over those two lines of code**

```
<Homepage.java>

    tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(this),
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homepage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**This is the class file related to above file**

```
<CustomPhoneStateListener.java>

public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
    super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: " + signalStrength);
    if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getGsmBitErrorRate "
                + signalStrength.getGsmBitErrorRate());
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getGsmSignalStrength "
                + signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength());
    } else if (signalStrength.getCdmaDbm() > 0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getCdmaDbm "
                + signalStrength.getCdmaDbm());
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getCdmaEcio "
                + signalStrength.getCdmaEcio());
    } else {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getEvdoDbm "
                + signalStrength.getEvdoDbm());
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getEvdoEcio "
                + signalStrength.getEvdoEcio());
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getEvdoSnr "
                + signalStrength.getEvdoSnr());
    }

          try {
        Method[] methods = android.telephony.SignalStrength.class
                .getMethods();
        for (Method mthd : methods) {
            if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteSignalStrength")
                    || mthd.getName().equals("getLteRsrp")
                    || mthd.getName().equals("getLteRsrq")
                    || mthd.getName().equals("getLteRssnr")
                    || mthd.getName().equals("getLteCqi")) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,
                        "onSignalStrengthsChanged: " + mthd.getName() + " "
                                + mthd.invoke(signalStrength));
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**The above code is related to measure signal **

Comment: `@+id/action_settings` must be defined in corresponding xml file

Comment: You should say what the exact error is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebuild/clean the project? try `build`->`clean project`. make sure you also have these resources in the respective folders i.e. `homepage.xml` in your res/menu folder and should have an item with i.d `action_settings`